# How to choose the attribute of a user-defined class that will be evaluated for built-in min() and max() functions?

Tags: python, class, object, max, min

I want to use Python's built-in [min()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and [max()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) functions on a collection of my `Point` objects. However, I want the `distance` attribute to be the compared value. How can I specify this in the class definition?

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y, distance):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.distance = distance

a = Point(3, 5, 2)
b = Point(5, 4, 1)
c = Point(8, 4, 5)

hopefully_b = min(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a key function:

```
from operator import attrgetter

max(a, b, c, key=attrgetter('distance'))
```

The [`operator.attrgetter()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) produces a callable that returns the named attribute for each object passed to it. You could achieve the same with a `lambda` callable:

```
max(a, b, c, key=lambda p: p.distance)
```

Alternatively, you can add special methods to the class to define how they should be compared; the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method defines how two instances are equal, and methods like [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) and friends are used when comparing two instances to see how they order. `max()` will then make use of these methods to find a 'largest' item, without a `key` function.

With the [`@functools.total_ordering()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) you only have to implement two of those; `__eq__` and one of the comparison methods:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y, distance):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.distance = distance

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return NotImplemented  # only the same type or subclasses
        return (self.x, self.y, self.distance) == (other.x, other.y, other.distance)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return NotImplemented  # only the same type or subclasses
        if (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y):
            return False  # same coordinates makes them equalish?
        return self.distance < other.distance
```

For `Point` objects this should probably be thought out more; what happens if distance is not equal but x and y are, for example?

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you provide some insight as to which attribute gets used when no key is specified (default behavior)?

Comment: @sgarza62: for classes without ordering methods, instances of the same type are ordered by `id()` value instead.

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer

Answer (score 2):

When using `min` and `max` without a special key function, the functions will use the order of the objects to determine its result. So you will have to implement an order for your `Point` class, making e.g. `a > b` work.

To do that, you will need to implement a number of [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__). That way you enable comparison between those objects. Since you likely want a proper order where `a < b` implies `b > a` etc., you can use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to implement a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) by just defining the equality and a single lower-than comparison:

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Point:
    def __init__ (self, x, y, distance):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.distance = distance

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        return (self.distance, self.x, self.y) < (other.distance, other.x, other.y)

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return (self.distance, self.x, self.y) == (other.distance, other.x, other.y)

    def __repr__ (self):
        return 'Point({}, {}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.distance)
```

```
>>> a, b, c = Point(3, 5, 2), Point(5, 4, 1), Point(8, 4, 5)
>>> min(a, b, c)
Point(5, 4, 1)
>>> max(a, b, c)
Point(8, 4, 5)
```